# Linear Interoplation, Can this be optimized to run faster?

Tags: c#

I have a simple procedure that's looping over a set of point data and doing linear interpolation to 'fill out' the data, I'm wondering if anyone can help giving some performance tips on my code and show me areas where i can optimize the code, thanks!

here code:

```
    static internal Point3D[] _data;
    static internal Point3dTree _kd;

    static internal int _interpolation_count = 0;
    static internal int _iteration_count = 0;
    static Dictionary<int, Point3D> Interpolated_Values = new Dictionary<int, Point3D>();

    static internal int _threasindex;
    static internal double[] _threasholds = new double[]
    {
        0.5,
        1.0,
        1.5,
        20.5
    };

    static internal double Interpolate(double x, double x0, double x1, double y0, double y1)
    {
        if ((x1 - x0) == 0)
            return (y0 + y1) / 2;

        return y0 + (x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new ProceduralTimer("Loading data"))
            _data = LasReader.GetData(@"C:\WindowsLP\SAMPLE_PROJECT\brisport2\area_cov.las");
        using (new ProceduralTimer("Bulding Kd tree"))
            _kd = new Point3dTree(_data, false);

        List<Point3D> InterpolatedData = _data.ToList();
        _data = null;

        using (new ProceduralTimer("Processing"))
        {
            int i = 0;
            var neighbours = new List<Point3D>();
            for (; i < InterpolatedData.Count; i++)
            {
            @rescan:
                neighbours = _kd.NearestNeighbours(new KdTreeNode<Point3D>(InterpolatedData[i]), _threasholds[_threasindex % _threasholds.Length]);

                if (neighbours.Count < 4 && _threasindex < _threasholds.Length)
                {
                    _threasindex++;
                    _iteration_count++;
                    goto rescan;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (neighbours.Count >= 4)
                    {
                        double[] xvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.X).ToArray();
                        double[] yvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Y).ToArray();
                        double[] zvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Z).ToArray();

                        Point3D pt = new Point3D();
                        pt.X = Math.Round(Interpolate(InterpolatedData[i].X, xvalues[0], xvalues[1], xvalues[2], xvalues[3]), 2);
                        pt.Y = Math.Round(Interpolate(InterpolatedData[i].Y, yvalues[0], yvalues[1], yvalues[2], yvalues[3]), 2);
                        pt.Z = Math.Round(Interpolate(InterpolatedData[i].Z, zvalues[0], zvalues[1], zvalues[2], zvalues[3]), 2);

                        Interpolated_Values[i] = pt;

                        _interpolation_count++;
                    }

                    _threasindex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is always worth asking "Why do you need this code to be optimized?", given that, according to Don Knuth, [premature optimisation is the root of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). If you **do** need to optimize the code, do you need to reduce time or space usage and, for either, how much are you prepared to increase one to reduce the other?

Comment: You can convert the for loop into a Parallel.ForEach method. Also, you can replace the goto with a do while loop for readability.

Comment: Expanding on Simon's comments: *what* do you want to optimize? Readability? Speed? Memory use? Code size? And under *what conditions* do you want the optimum? Without data we cannot give meaningful help. Give serious thought to Simon's question.

Answer (score 1):

All of the language features you're using are pretty low level except for the linq to extract the x y z values.

```
double[] xvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.X).ToArray();
double[] yvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Y).ToArray();
double[] zvalues = neighbours.Select(_ => _.Z).ToArray();
```

Try one iteration through the `neighbours` collection extracting the X Y Z values:

```
List<double> xvalues = new List<double>();
List<double> yvalues = new List<double>();
List<double> zvalues = new List<double>();

foreach(var neighbour in neighbours)
{
    xvalues.Add(neighbour.X);
    yvalues.Add(neighbour.Y);
    zvalues.Add(neighbour.Z);
}
```